# Подводные камни при создании игр: авторские права, лицензии и прочее

Tags: разработка-игр, ios

Например, появилась идея - написать игру, по фильму/мультфильму;  => необходимо будет включить в игру персонажей, похожих на героев фильма/мультфильма, вопрос: нужно ли получать права на их использование?   Какие ещё, могут всплыть, нюансы - юридического характера, при разработке игры?

Интересен ваш опыт.

Comment: Я думаю, в нашем законодательстве, если кажется, что что-то похоже на повод прикопаться, то обязательно окажется, что не кажется, а это и есть повод прикопаться. Особенно любое использование того, что где-то уже было, кроме тех вещей, на к-ые срок действия авторских прав уже прошел.

Comment: в нашем законодательстве, если захотят прикопаться - прикопаются в любом случае

Comment: а если фильм/мультфильм иностранный, от Disney или WB ?=) Интересует юридический аспект, нужно ли получение прав на использование героев? И если будут рисоваться спрайты, они же не совсем будут похожи на них..
Или например спортивная игра и в ней использутся персонажи на основе реально существующих игроков футбола/баскетбола...

Comment: нечего точно про твой вопрос не скажу, но например, НФСка покупает права на использование машин в игре, а во флетАут - свои машины придумали, что бы не платить. В случае с ютюбом - он просто ограничивает зоны показа ролика, если нарушаются права, а айсторе каждое приложение проходит проверку - они то тебе и скажут =) в гуглПлее - не так строго =)

Comment: вот это уже интересно=) спасибо!

Comment: вот нашёл пару ссылочек, тут конечно не про разработку игр, но рассматривается:
1) авторские права на образы мульт-героев http://www.simpo.biz/news/index.php?ELEMENT_ID=1756  
2) мерчандайзинг персонажа и личности http://www.wipo.int/sme/ru/documents/merchandising.htm

Comment: @Gorets можешь свой коммент перенести в ответы? хочу приянть его как ответ =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Интересен ваш опыт.
```

Вряд ли кто-то вообще мог сам создать свою игру, чтобы в ней было что-либо более-менее похоже на элемент из настоящего мира, за использование которого надо было бы платить. Я уверен, что одному создать такую игру никому не получится, именно поэтому крупные игровые компании разбивают создание игр на мельчайшие части распределяют их между разработчиками, дизайнерами, модельерами и т.д. Насколько знаю, создание средней игры( типа NFS ) разбивается минимум на 800 частей, где одна часть предполагает создание( моделирование ) определенной улицы, другая - встраивание физического движка для эффектов торможения, скольжения и т.д.

Поэтому, скажу прямо, что вам можно по этому поводу особо не париться. Для начала создайте хотя бы одну 3D-модель, которая, как вы думаете может быть из реального мира и затем посмотрите, похожа ли она на то, что задумывалось. Да и тем более пользователей у игры, которую создает 1 человек( я имею ввиду игры типа гонок, простецких стрелялок и т.д ) вряд ли будет много...да и вообще, Россия - такая страна, что в ней можно почти все( а многое нахаляву ). Вот так же с авторскими правами.

Answer (score -1):

Соглашусь с Gorets: если хочешь без проблем и последующей толкотни в судах за нарушенное право расплачиваться, ты либо платишь по заключенным лицензионным договорам, либо придумываешь и рисуешь свое и никому ничего не платишь :)